# Running downloaded source code on eclipse

Tags: android

I just downloaded the source code of an application 'MyTracks' from code.google.com, using a mercury client. Now the problem with it is, if I try running the application through eclipse, using 'create project from existing source' it gives an error, that the directory that I have selected doesn't  have a manifest file, so its invalid. I checked the downloaded source and the source files on code.google.com, the manifest file was no where to be found. Now how do I run the application?

Answer (score 0):

MyTracks has various projects, you must have tryed to import the main folder, but you should import each project separately.

Comment: So, how do I go about doing that? You mean to say that I should import the sub folders one by one? And will importing only one folder do the job?

Comment: Yes, you should import the subfolder, but I don't know the project to know if just some of the folders are necessary.